# Links to hidden comments shows "Show 1 More Comments" even when there are no others

Tags: support, comments, comment-links

Follow this link to a comment (found in the notification inbox).

https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/106891

As of writing, it links to the **last** comment on the original question, which would normally be hidden.

There's a link just below saying `add / show 1 more comment`, but there is no other comment.

It seems like it's not expanding the comments in a consistent way.
The UI should look the same whether I browsed to the question, and clicked `show more`, or whether I clicked on a comment link to a hidden comment.

Comment: It shows "add comment" for me, which is especially wrong since I'm not even logged in.

Comment: I see "add comment" too.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Do either of you have an account there? Possibly that's why you get something other than what I get. In either case it doesn't seem right (when logged in it says there's another comment, but there isn't and when not logged in it says you can add a comment).

Comment: I have an [account](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/252/kiamlaluno) there. The fact Tim Stone doesn't have an account there suggests that is not what makes the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One user self-deleted a comment there, which might be the source of the discrepancy. Possibly a timing issue where the delete happened but the denormalized count of comments wasn't changed.

At any rate, it seems OK now, and we normalize answer/comment counts daily to catch these sorts of things automatically.. in summary, just wait. :)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a list anywhere that lists what is cached in this way (i.e. updated daily/weekly etc.)?