# Comment auto-expansion lies to anonymous users

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, javascript

While looking at [this comment issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120837/150235) I noticed that when the comments were auto-expanded for me, the "add comment" link was appearing...which was unexpected, since I wasn't logged into that site. While the erroneous "1 more comment" there may have been a temporary glitch, the "add comment" link appearing for anonymous users is a bug.

When the comments are auto-expanded, they're loaded via `StackExchange.comments.loadAll()`, which doesn't set up the promised handler that would normally hide that link. That's fine if you can comment, since the text area isn't shown by default in this case and requires an extra click. But, if you can't comment, there's nothing that currently checks if that link should be removed anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a vigorous game of ping pong, I have fixed this issue.

We used to only expose direct comment links in your [activity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity) and [responses](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=responses) tabs, but  that was changed over the weekend, linking comments on a Question/Show page and in the global inbox.

The added traffic revealed this javascript bug.

Comment: Fix will be deployed tonight.

Comment: The real question is, did you win the ping pong game? If not, I can go file a bug against Careers to distract Punyon for a bit.

Comment: When Punyon was on my team, I did **not** win.