# Links to hidden comments is displayed despite hidden comments already being shown

Tags: bug, comments

Related question: [Links to hidden comments shows "Show 1 More Comments" even when there are no others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120837/links-to-hidden-comments-shows-show-1-more-comments-even-when-there-are-no-oth)

Here's a link (from my inbox) to a comment that's initially hidden:
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/12625561

Despite hidden comments being shown (to show the linked comment) the "Add/Show 2 more comments" link is shown.

In the related question (above) it was noted that someone deleted a comment which may have mucked things up temporarily, I'm wondering if this is the case this time too.

Even if it is because of a deleted comment, should it be fixed so that we don't get the error/misinformation at all?

---

One additional note: It appears this will only happen to me (the one who commented).
Possibly it's triggered by the "Avoid extended discussions..." message its self being implemented as a comment (that would only be applicable/visible to me).

Comment: Can't reproduce - clicking your comment link expanded the comments and there was just "add comment" link.

Comment: That's interesting that it does show for me. Perhaps it's because the "Avoid extended discussion...." message is implemented as a comment and would only be visible to me.

Comment: Yup that might be the case - worth adding to your post.

Comment: I do see this often...  I will have to keep an eye out for it and see if I can get repro steps.